# Repeatedly applying a function

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of numbers:

```
allNums = 
 {2, 5, 10, 17, 26, 1, 3, 7, 13, 21, 31, 1, 2, 11, 28, 53, 1, 6, 19, 40, 69}
```

I calculate all possible pairs of two numbers from the values in this list:

```
allCombs = Permutations[allNums, {2}]
```

and the sums of all those possible pairs

```
allSums = Total /@ allCombs
```

Now I'm choosing a number, let's say 61, and look if this numbers is a sum of  the possible pairs in `allCombs` and extract the values

```
Num = 61; Extract[allCombs, Position[allSums, Num]]
```

which gives me:

```
{{21, 40}, {40, 21}}
```

My problem is to do the same process again for the retrieved values above until no longer possible, i.e., selecting a number and looking if this number can be represented as the sum of a pair in `allCombs`. I'm unable to find an elegant solution for this.

For example, now I would take the values 21, 40, 40, 21 and calculate

```
Num = 21; Extract[allCombs, Position[allSums, Num]]
```

and

```
Num = 40; Extract[allCombs, Position[allSums, Num]]
```

and the same for 40 and 21 (which yields the same values after all, but I also don't know how to remove those duplicate values since they are in reverse order).

Now I would like to repeat this process again and again until no longer possible, e.g. for 21 I extract:

```
{{2, 19}, {10, 11}, {11, 10}, {19, 2}}
```

then I would repeat the process for 2,19,10,11 and so on. I hope what I mean is clear :).

I was trying to play around with the `Nest`, `NestList` and NestWhileList`, but I didn't manage to make it work.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Also, what is the format of the data you want as a result? All of the lists? A list of the numbers?

Comment: I take that back. You *do* want to use `Nest` and `NestList`. The trick is to create the right function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `allCombs = Select[Permutations[allNums, {2}], OrderedQ]` to check only ordered permutations.

Using this:

```
findSum[num_] := Extract[allCombs, Position[allSums, num]]
findSums[nums_] := Flatten[findSum /@ DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[nums]], 1]

FixedPointList[findSums, {61}, 100] // Column
```

> {
>
> {{61}},
>
> {{{21, 40}}},
>
> {{{2, 19}, {10, 11}, {19, 21}}},
>
> {{{1, 1}, {2, 17}, {6, 13}, {3, 7}, {5, 6}, {1, 10}, {2, 19}, {10, 
>       11}}},
>
> {{{1, 1}, {7, 10}, {6, 11}, {1, 5}, {2, 11}, {3, 10}, {6, 7}, {1, 
>       2}, {2, 5}, {1, 6}, {2, 3}, {3, 7}, {2, 17}, {6, 13}, {5, 6}, {1, 
>       10}}},
>
> {{{2, 5}, {1, 6}, {3, 7}, {1, 5}, {5, 6}, {1, 10}, {2, 3}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {7, 10}, {6, 11}, {2, 11}, {3, 10}, {6, 7}}},
>
> {{{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {1, 5}, {1, 2}, {2, 5}, {1, 6}, {3, 7}, {5, 6}, {1,
>        10}}},
>
> {{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 5}, {2, 5}, {1, 6}, {3, 7}}},
>
> {{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 5}, {2, 5}, {1, 6}}},
>
> {{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 5}}},
>
> {{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}}},
>
> {{{1, 1}, {1, 2}}},
>
> {{{1, 1}}},
>
> {{}},
>
> {{}}
>   }

([`FixedPointList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FixedPointList.html) is like `NestList`, except that it stops when the result doesn't change any more, when it found the fixed point)

Comment: Thanks! is it possible to order the pairs (maybe without removing duplicates) in order to know which pairs sum up to the higher number. For example {{{2,19},{10,11}},{{21,19}}. Otherwise it becomes quite difficult to sort out which numbers belong together.

Comment: @holistic: Sure, just apply `Flatten` and `DeleteDuplicates` earlier

Comment: awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

First, let's find all the numbers that are part of possible pairs, which we can do in a more direct fashion using `Pick`.

```
 selectTotals[combos : {___List}, totals : {___?NumericQ}, nums_List] :=
   DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@Pick[combos, totals, Alternatives @@ nums];
```

Then we can find all the combinations using `Subset` (since order doesn't matter, this will check half as many pairs as using `Permutations`) and use `FixedPointList` (as in [nixie's answer][1]) to go until the list of results stops changing (on the off chance that the list doesn't collapse into an empty list, this is more robust):

```
iteratedTotals[nums_, init_] :=
 Module[{combos = Subsets[nums, {2}], totals},
  totals = Total[combos, {2}];

  Most@FixedPointList[selectTotals[combos, totals, #] &, 
    Flatten[{init}]]];
```

I used `Most` to get rid of the extra duplicated result at the end. Calling the function on `allNums` yields the following:

```
iteratedTotals[allNums, 61]
(* {{61}, {21, 40}, {2, 19, 10, 11, 21}, 
    {2, 17, 19, 5, 6, 10, 1, 11, 3, 7, 13}, 
    {2, 5, 17, 1, 3, 11, 6, 10, 7, 13}, 
    {2, 5, 1, 3, 11, 6, 10, 7}, 
    {2, 5, 1, 3, 6, 10, 7}, 
    {2, 5, 1, 3, 6, 7}, {2, 5, 1, 3, 6}, 
    {2, 1, 3, 5}, {2, 1, 3}, {2, 1}, {1}, {}} *)
```

#### Update:

Changing things to preserve the pairs is actually pretty straightforward; you just  `Flatten` at a different time, like so:

```
 selectCombinations[combos : {___List}, totals : {___?NumericQ}, nums_List] := 
   DeleteDuplicates@Pick[combos, totals, Alternatives @@ Flatten[nums]];

 iteratedCombinations[nums_, init_] :=
  Module[{combos = Subsets[nums, {2}], totals}, 
    totals = Total[combos, {2}];
    Most@FixedPointList[
     selectCombinations[combos, totals, #] &, {init}]];

iteratedCombinations[allNums, 61]
(* {{61}, {{21, 40}}, ...} *)
```

Comment: Thanks..very helpful! The problem is, that by removing the duplicates the numbers get kind of mixed up, so that it is not clear which numbers sum to e.g. 21 and 40. A list of the form {{{2,19},{10,11}},{{21,19}}} would be better, but I'm not sure how to adapt your code.